# How to use apostrope in meta description

Tags: 7, meta-tags

Whenever I use an apostrophe in a meta description the browser prints the code as `&#039;`. Is there a way to prevent this?

These are coming trough a custom module that builds out the page.

Comment: How does it get there in the first place? Module Metatags? Custom module? Twig?

Comment: @leymannx, added a bit more info above but I'm new to Drupal so not really sure how it works.

Comment: Show code that builds/fetches the tag names...

Answer (score -1):

When using apostrophe in a taxonomy it is displayed as `&amp#039;` in the html-tittle of the page

The problem could be fixed by disabling the module "Metatag: Views" or updating the `metatag.inc` accordingly:
replacing the `check_plain()` by `filter_xss()`

```
class DrupalTitleMetaTag extends DrupalTextMetaTag {

  public function getElement(array $options = array()) {
    $element = array();
    $value = filter_xss($this->getValue($options));
    $element['#attached']['metatag_set_preprocess_variable'][] = array('html', 'head_title', $value);
    $element['#attached']['metatag_set_preprocess_variable'][] = array('html', 'head_array', array('title' => $value));
    return $element;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to hack the Metatag module?